# json4s - Ignore field of particular type during serialization

Tags: scala, json4s

Suppose I have some marker `trait Ignore`
I want all fields that are marked with this trait to be ignored during serialization.

So if I have class

```
case class A(a: Int) extends Ignore
case class B(f: String, a: A, d: Int)
```

the json for B after serialization shouldn't conatin `a` field.

**NOTE**: I know that there is an opportunity to ignore field by name, but this is not what I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `CustomSerializer`.
You can customize only serialization by providing an empty `PartialFunction` as deserializer:

```
trait Ignore
case class A(a: Int) extends Ignore
case class B(f: String, a: A, d: Int)

implicit val formats = DefaultFormats +
  new CustomSerializer[Ignore](formats => (
  PartialFunction.empty,
  { case _: Ignore => JNothing }
  ))

// prints "{"f":"x","d":2}"
println(Serialization.write(B("x", A(1), 2)))
// deserializes to B(x,A(1),2)
println(Serialization.read[B]("""{"f":"x","a":{"a":1},"d":2}"""))
```

edit: **At the time of writing (3.3.0) json4s-native has a bug that incorrectly renders the serialized object if the *first* field is ignored (e.g. `case class B(a: A, ...)`. I suggest using json4s-jackson until the problem is solved**

Using first `Extraction.decompose` and after `Serialization` seems to solve the issue:

```
trait Ignore
case class A(a: Int) extends Ignore
case class B(a: A, d: Int)

implicit val formats = DefaultFormats +
  new CustomSerializer[Ignore](formats => (
    PartialFunction.empty,
    { case _: Ignore => JNothing }
    ))

// prints {,"d":2}
println(Serialization.write(B(A(1), 2)))
// prints {"d":2}
println(Serialization.write(Extraction.decompose(B(A(1), 2))))
```

Comment: Yes, this works, but if I put a field at the beginning of the B's fields it produces invalid json. E.g.: `case class B(a: A, d: Int)` produces `"{,"d":2}"` How to fix that?

Comment: @maks It works for me: `{"d":2}`. Are you using an old json4s version? I'm on 3.3.0

Comment: @maks Ok, I haven't checked but I think my code works because I'm using json4s-jackson. Are you using native?

Comment: @maks Confirmed, it's a json4s Issue. This is definitely a bug, I'll open an issue on github, I suggest using jackson anyway because it's faster

Comment: @maks I found a workaround, but you have to change the serialization code until (and if ever) the bug is solved